# Is WinPcap optimal for 1 gbps NIC

Tags: c++, networking, pcap, libpcap, winpcap

Image data is coming in to my NIC at 200 mb/s. I'm using winpcap to capture this data. This data essentially just needs to straight to my application level - I don't need any filters. To maximize efficiency, my sixth sense tell me the two data stores (from NIC driver buffer to Winkpcap kernel buffer; from kernel buffer to my user buffer) is inefficient and wastes CPU. Is it possible to optimize the system? Or are there better methods of achieving this? (maybe a pf_ring type solution for windows)

Comment: Forgive me if I'm way off the mark (I don't do much network programming), but why not read from the interface directly in your application (e.g. with a raw socket)?

Comment: no, that's a good point. I believe it's known as kernel bypass, but I can't find anything for windows -- only linux

Comment: For Kernel Bypass in windows you need to do your own NIC drivers. Use WinPcap, it is as good as it is going to get.

Answer (score 0):

This is how you can do it:

- Configure the WinPcap buffer to a large value (100MiB for example) using `pcap_setbuff`
- Set the read timeout to a large value, (1 second for example), argument `read_timeout` of `pcap_open`
- **Most Important**: Make sure you take packets out of the buffer faster than the NIC receives them, Example for 200Mbps, you need `60B / 200Mbps = 2.4µs` per packet to make sure no packets are dropped.

Answer (score 0):

You might also try [Npcap](https://npcap.org), if you're using Windows 7 or newer.